# Why links are not linked if edited comment?

Tags: plugins, comments, urls, links, comments-template

I am using the plugin `front end editor` to edit posts.. This works very well in posts, where all links are perfectly visible if I have edited a post. For some reason, if I edit a comment and there are links in the post, I can't see the links and can't click on them because it's not linked. I must refresh the page to see the comment linking to where they were linking...

Is there a solution without having to refresh the page? Why is this happening at all?

Comment: Have you asked on that plugins's support forum? This one, I think: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/front-end-editor

Comment: Yes, but frankly got no answer on that one...

Comment: That is a lot of code to dig through but @scribu is listed as an author. Perhaps he will notice the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin author has solved the issue. He says:

> I have encountered this bug before, but I just now realized what's
>   causing it: the 'comment_text' filter is not applied on the updated
>   comment content. The make_clickable() function, which makes the links
>   in the content clickable, is hooked to this 'comment_text' filter.
>
> Anyway, it's fixed now:
>   https://github.com/scribu/wp-front-end-editor/commit/e590a39522c89ca8016e52f7dcc26d33d552e69c
>
> You can try out that fix by downloading the [Development Version](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/front-end-editor.zip)
>   (2.3.2-alpha).